# Downloading PDF's with Webdriver

Tags: macos, firefox, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download pdfs with selenium webdriver with python bindings on OS X 10.8.

I actually need the pdf file, not just check if it the download link works. As I understand it, I need to set the firefox profile to download the pdf content type, rather than 'preview' which is the default.

My code to open an instance of firefox is:

```
def Engage():
    print "Start Up FIREFOX"
    ## Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
    profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/Download_Files/tmp/"))
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('application/pdf'))
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
    return driver
```

I have also tried initially setting the profile as :

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
## replacing :: profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()
## the other attributes remained
```

This has the same results

This profile opens the pdf in preview mode in a new window, rather than download it.

I double checked the content type through requests and was able to confirm it as "application/pdf":

```
import requests
print requests.head('mywebsite.com').headers['content-type']
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was facing a similar situation sometime back. Solution is quite easy. By default the settings in firefox opens pdf files rather than allowing you to download it. To overcome this type config:about in the browser and type pdfjs.disabled double click on the option. The value should change from false to true. Restart the browser and try opening any pdf file. It will download the file instead of opening it in the browser. Happy coding.

Comment: I really thought this would do it, and while it has made pdfs on my default browser auto download, it does not download pdfs in the firefox instance webdriver creates. I need to find a way to make that config change to the webdriver's profile. Thank you for the advice though.

Comment: Why not change this value in a new firefox profile and launch that profile. It has worked  for me. Just a suggestion.

Comment: How would I change it if firefox launches a new profile every time I use webdriver? I tried to set the profile to no avail. Is there a way to open firefox, use webdriver to alter the about:config page, and restart firefox in the same profile?

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode you will have to create your firefox profile and change the settings in that and invoke that profile when starting firefoxdriver. To create a new profile close firefox. Go to run dialog and type firefox -ProfileManager. Follow the steps create a profile for Ex. Selenium and launch firefox. Now change the pdf settings. Once done invoke this profile using following code.                                                     ProfilesIni sel = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile pro = sel.getProfile("Selenium");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(pro);

Comment: It says 'sel' in 'ProfilesIni sel= new ProfilesIni();' is invalid syntax.

Comment: Got it. I finally found my firefox profile path. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem. My code is in Java, but I'm sure you can transfer the properties to match in python. Here is what worked or me (note you need to specify a path to a directory that you can write to):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference( "browser.download.folderList", 2 );
profile.setPreference( "browser.download.dir", <YOUR DOWNLOAD PATH> );
profile.setPreference( "plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf" );
profile.setPreference(
                "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",   
"application/csv,text/csv,application/pdfss, application/excel" );
profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
profile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
```